# unique in .hbm.xml file not raising exception

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am having the following in my .hbm.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                                    namespace="Core.Domain.Model"
                                    assembly="Core">

  <class name="Category" table="Categories" dynamic-update="true">
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="Id" column="Id" type="Guid">
      <generator class="guid"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name" length="100">
    <column name="Name" unique="true" index="IX_Category"/>
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

I am having the following code, however, I can see that no exception is being raised when I am inserting a duplicate value for the Name field. Why is that so?

```
 void IRepository<Category>.Save(Category entity)
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
            {
            using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    session.Save(entity);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
            scope.Complete();
            }    
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The *unique* attribute is only used when [generating a DDL schema from a mapping](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#toolsetguide-s1) (hbm).

If you want to check uniqueness with NHibernate, it is data validation and you should look [NHibernate validator](http://nhforge.org/wikis/validator/nhibernate-validator-1-0-0-documentation.aspx).
And as Rafael said you have to write your own validator.

You can also check the [*natural-id*](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-naturalid) element.

Unless you absolutely need to validate uniqueness on application side, this [sample](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/10/validation-through-persistence.html) and [this one](http://sharp-architecture.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/SharpArch/SharpArch.Data/NHibernate/EntityDuplicateChecker.cs) make me think it may be better to let the database do this job.

Comment: Noting that even with the excellent NHibernate Validator, you would have to write your own validation, because it obviously does not have an [Unique] validator (which would require a hit to the database).

Comment: True, edited to include that it may be only a good practice if the validation have absolutely to be done on the persisted data.

Answer (score 2):

Did NHibernate generate the database schema for you? Because even though you set the property as `unique`, if the schema does not have the `unique` constraint, it will do nothing. Basically, that property won't query the database looking for uniqueness; it will only set the [**SQL constraint**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) on `insert`.

Comment: Thanks, I have modified the database but now i`m having the error message Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__Categories__0EA330E9'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Categories'. The statement has been terminated, however, I would prefer to have the error message generated by NHibernate,(e.InnerException.Message i.e something like Message = "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Categories' with unique index 'IX_Category'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."...I would prefer nHibernate to generate the throw the exception message

Comment: Like JoeBilly said, look into NHibernate Validator. You can then make NHibernate check for uniqueness and throw whatever you want.