# FluentNHibernate. Give a custom Name for Unique Key Constraint

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Hello I'm wondering how to rename the default unique key constraint such as:

```
UQ__Company__4E5D936F3493CFA7
```

into something like this:

```
UQ_Company_CompanyName
```

Here is the mapping for the `Company` class:

```
public class CompanyMap : ClassMap<Company>
{
    public CompanyMap()
    {        
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        // The below UniqueKey name doesn't apply as expected
        Map(x => x.CompanyName).UniqueKey("UQ_Company_CompanyName");
        Map(x => x.Description);
        Map(x => x.CreationDate).Not.Update();
    }
}
```

#### Note:

I've found that there are such things as [Conventions](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Conventions) in fluent nhibernate which gives some control over mapping, but unfortunately didn't figured out yet how to use them to control the UQ_Naming...

Comment: How about using `.Column("UQ_My_Name")`?

Comment: As I know `.Column("...")` is for setting the column name only isn't it?

Comment: Deriving from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726478/unique-in-hbm-xml-file-not-raising-exception and my own thoughts: add `.Unique()` before `UniqueKey()`.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately this isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it isn't possible :(
https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1955
https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1165